# How to substitute Boolean value from values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

In some of the examples I am following, I see, for a string value, I can do this:

```
{{- with .Values.cookieDomain }}
- --cookieDomain={{- toString . }}
{{- end }}
```

with this, if I have, e.g. `cookieDomain: .mydomain.com` in the *values.yaml*, the template gets the correct value.

How to do the same/similar for boolean values?
For example, if I have this: `proxyPass: true` in *values.yaml*, how do I interpret that in template, as there is no `toBool` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `toString`, in your example, is actually moot, if the value contained in `cookieDoman` is already a string it will just do nothing.

What you have to understand in `with .Values.cookieDoman` is that the context has now changed from `.` being the root of the variables definition to being `.Values.cookieDoman`.

A little like doing a change of directory in a computer, if I `cd /tmp`, then `./some_file` looks for a file in `/tmp/some_file`. Now if I `cd /etc`, the same command, `./some_file`, will now look for a file `/etc/some_file`.

> This controls variable scoping. Recall that `.` is a reference to the *current scope*. So `.Values` tells the template to find the `Values` object in the current scope.

<sup>*Source: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#modifying-scope-using-with*</sup>

So, in your example, it is fine enough already to do

```
flags:
{{- with .Values.cookieDomain }}
  - --cookieDomain={{- . }}
{{- end }}
```

This will renders in

```yaml
flags:
  - --cookieDomain=.mydomain.com
```

And, so, if you have a boolean, it is the exact same:

```
flags:
{{- with .Values.proxyPass }}
  - --proxyPass={{- . }}
{{- end }}
```

Will give:

```yaml
flags:
  - --proxyPass=true
```